# Adding a column to a spark dataset and transforming data

Tags: java, apache-spark, dataset

I'm loading a parquet file as a spark dataset. I can query and create new datasets from the query. Now, I would like to add a new column to the dataset ("hashkey") and generate the values (e.g. md5sum(nameValue)). How can i achieve this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();

    sparkConf.setAppName("Hello Spark");
    sparkConf.setMaster("local");

    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
            .config("spark.master", "local").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:\\spark_warehouse")
            .getOrCreate();

    Dataset<org.apache.spark.sql.Row> df = spark.read().parquet("meetup.parquet");
    df.show();

    df.createOrReplaceTempView("tmpview");

    Dataset<Row> namesDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM tmpview where name like 'Spark-%'");

    namesDF.show();

}
```

The output looks like this:

```
+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+--------------------+
|         name|meetup_date|going|organizer|              topics|
+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+--------------------+
|    Spark-H20| 2016-01-01|   50|airisdata|[h2o, repeated sh...|
|   Spark-Avro| 2016-01-02|   60|airisdata|    [avro, usecases]|
|Spark-Parquet| 2016-01-03|   70|airisdata| [parquet, usecases]|
+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add spark sql function for **MD5** in you query.

```
Dataset<Row> namesDF = spark.sql("SELECT *, md5(name) as modified_name FROM tmpview where name like 'Spark-%'");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dataset<Row> ds = sqlContext.read()
    .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
    .option("inferSchema", "true")
    .option("header", "true")
    .option("delimiter","|")
    .load("/home/cloudera/Desktop/data.csv");
ds.printSchema();
```

will print this :

```
root
 |-- ReferenceValueSet_Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ReferenceValueSet_Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code_Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CURR_FLAG: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)

Dataset<Row> df1 = ds.withColumn("Key", functions.lit(1));
        df1.printSchema();
```

after adding above code, it will append one column with constant values.

```
root
 |-- ReferenceValueSet_Id: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ReferenceValueSet_Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code_Description: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code_Type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Code: string (nullable = true)
 |-- CURR_FLAG: string (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_CREATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- REC_UPDATE_DATE: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- Key: integer (nullable = true)
```

you can see column with name Key is added to the dataset.

If you wanted to add some column inplace of the constunt value, you can use below code to add it.

```
Dataset<Row> df1 = ds.withColumn("Key", functions.lit(ds.col("Code")));
        df1.printSchema();
        df1.show();
```

now it will print watever the values is there into the column CODE. into the newly aded column named Key.